# Typo3 Backend JS ContextMenu - open Extensionmanager

Tags: typo3

In 'sysext/beuser/Resources/Public/JavaScript/ContextMenuActions.js' there is an action which defines the following:

```
ContextMenuActions.openPermissionsModule = function(table, uid) {
    if (table === 'pages') {
      top.TYPO3.Backend.ContentContainer.setUrl(
        top.TYPO3.settings.AccessPermissions.moduleUrl +
        '&id=' + uid +
        '&tx_beuser_system_beusertxpermission[action]=edit' +
        '&tx_beuser_system_beusertxpermission[controller]=Permission' +
        '&returnUrl=' + ContextMenuActions.getReturnUrl()
      );
    }
  };
```

I defined a custom ContextMenu element in the Backend for the pagetree. I tried to find some functions to go to the Extensionmanager-Settings the same way like it is done in 'sysext/beuser/Resources/Public/JavaScript/ContextMenuActions.js' for the PermissionModule, w/o success. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, just use:

```
showModule: function(mod, params) {
        params = params || '';
        var record = this.getRecordFromName(mod);
        this.loadModuleComponents(record, params);
        this.ensurePageInTreeSelected();
      },
```